# Get the href link of an element with classname having spaces

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

I have been trying to get the link of an element using the class name but always getting an error that no element found

```
List<IWebElement> LinkElements =  Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementsByClassName("column.wrap-text").ToList();
```

I somehow managed to get the links I want using the below code but I know that is not a good approach.

```
try
    {
            Selenium.Selenium.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(txt_url.Text);

            List<IWebElement> LinkElements = Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementsByTagName("a").ToList();

            List<string> ValidLinks = new List<string>();

            foreach (IWebElement LinkElement in LinkElements)
            {
                string LinkString = LinkElement.GetAttribute("href");
                if (LinkString != null)
                {
                    if (LinkString.Contains("documents"))
                    {
                        list.Items.Add(LinkString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
```

Below is the html code for the element I want to extract the href link("/view/garnimii@/Testing%20Folder/MyFile.txt") with the title name in it. I have tried every possible way but not able to read the element with the findbyclassname or findbyxpath(which is very vague here). can anyone please help me with this?

```
 <div class="wrapper fluid-element">
 <div class="wrapper fluid-element">
 <div class="wrapper fluid-element">
 <div class="column wrap-text">
 <a title="MyFile.txt"  href="https://drive.corp.amazon.com/documents/garnimii@/Testing%20Folder/MyFile.txt">MyFile.txt</a 
>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column actions resource-actions-view">
<a data-turbolink="true" href="/view/garnimii@/Testing%20Folder/MyFile.txt"><i class="fa fa- 
external-link"></i> View
</a></div>
<div class="column actions resource-actions-share">
<a data-target="#resource-modal-share" data-toggle="modal" 
href="/share/garnimii@/Testing%20Folder/MyFile.txt">
<i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share
</a>
</div>
<div class="column actions resource-actions-rename resource-header-actions">
<a data-resource-basename="MyFile.txt" data-resource-id="8a520062-5dbe-46ba-b4b0-b672f6481c17"         
 data-root-path="/" data-target="#resource-modal-rename" data-toggle="modal" href="#resource- 
 modal-rename">
 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Rename
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

---

Update

```
   foreach (IWebElement LinkElement in LinkElements)
   { 
       string LinkString = LinkElement.GetAttribute("title");  
       if (LinkString != null) 
       { 
         if(LinkString.Contains("myfile.txt"))
         {  
            list.Items.Add(LinkString.GetAttribute('href'));
         }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even try with `//a` xpath.

```
List<IWebElement> LinkElements = Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementsByXpath("//a");

List<string> ValidLinks = new List<string>();

foreach (IWebElement LinkElement in LinkElements){
        Console.WriteLine(LinkElement.GetAttribute('href'))
}
```

print all the `GetAttribute` with `href` first. and if your output contains all the href then we can proceed further with adding into other list.

**Update :**

```
string LinkString = Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementByXpath("//a[@title='MyFile.txt']").GetAttribute('href')
```

Comment: this is something I have already pasted in my question. did not want this approach as it will increase the time to get all the links from the whole page if the files in it are more

Comment: You are using Selenium, how many `a` tag do we have in the web page ? also Selenium will have view port. It would not load all `a` tag in the page.

Comment: Alot. like 113 as far as I can see. looping through all of them will take a lot of memory and time. can i directly get the href link where the title=myfile.txt by using any xpath or css selector?

Comment: `string LinkString = Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementByXpath("//a[title='MyFile.txt']").GetAttribute('href')`

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq : please try the updated code above.

Comment: Yes, I tried the updated code, it is throwing {"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//a[title='MyFile.txt']\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)"}

Comment: GarnimittaIshaq : my bad, it should have been @title, please try now, updated above.

Comment: Still the same error,
tried this and it worked, string LisnkString = Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(text(),'MyFile.txt')]").GetAttribute("href").ToString();

Comment: No try this, `Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(@title,'MyFile.txt')]").GetAttribute("href")`

Comment: I got how to read the classnames with gaps from prophet answer and the href part was from your one which was my end answer required

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq : always use `.` with multiple classes, to convert to css selector

Comment: One last question. How can I actually get all the titles from the page? like let's suppose there are 'MyFile.txt', 'MyFile2.txt'. and there are in the title tag. if I want to just fetch all the titles without giving a search input. what shall I do?

Comment: use this xpath : `//a[contains(@title,'MyFile')]`, this does not have 1, 2, 3 so it will match will all visible nodes containing that myfile

Comment: No I mean I don't know what the title will be that is the example. cause files get uploaded on a daily basis on the browser and i can just get all the file names by the title tag.I don't know what contains in that list so just want to fetch all of them

Comment: find all elements matching xpath `//*[@title]` will give you a list of such elements. Then you can iterate this list to get each element title content

Comment: then you will have to use `//a[@title]` to represent all `a` tag with title attribute

Answer (score 1):

`FindElementsByClassName` can locate element by single class name.
For multiple class names you should use XPath or CSS selector.
So instead of

```
List<IWebElement> LinkElements =  Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementsByClassName("column.wrap-text").ToList();
```

Try using

```
List<IWebElement> LinkElements =  Selenium.Selenium.driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("div.column.wrap-text").ToList();
```

Comment: cssselector is working only to get the contents. but when looping it and trying to get the link where title="MyFile.txt", I am not able to get any link when using get attributes. Not sure where I am going wrong. Can we use something like FindElementsByCssSelector("a.title")

Comment: Can you show your code where you `looping and trying to get the link where title="MyFile.txt"`? I guess I know what is the problem, but you didn't show that in the question details

Comment: Ah, yeah. That is the question. I was not able to read the elements at first place due to the gaps in between. so could not go further. But i would do the same approach as I did for href for getting the title as well. I know that does not work, but i did try

Comment: foreach (IWebElement LinkElement in LinkElements)
                {
                    string LinkString = LinkElement.GetAttribute("title");
                    if (LinkString != null)
                    {
                        if (LinkString.Contains("myfile.txt"))
                        {
                            list.Items.Add(LinkString.GetAttribute('href'));
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: Do all these elements displayed on the screen / inside the view or you should scroll to them? What screen size do you set for driver?

Comment: It is displayed on the screen. need not need to scroll